# How do I prevent a boolean from being undefined in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

For the `isSelected` status of my tri-state checkbox, I only want to allow the values `true`, `false` and `null`. I want to prevent it from being `undefined`.

Here is what I tried:

```
type CheckboxState = true | false | null;

class MyCheckboxProps {
    isSelected: CheckboxState;

    constructor() {
        this.isSelected = 'some string'; // doesn't compile - good
        this.isSelected = false; // compiles - good
        this.isSelected = null; // compiles - good
        this.isSelected = undefined; // compiles - WHY?
    }
}
```

It seems that the TS compiler treats my custom `CheckboxState` type exactly as if it were a primitive `boolean`.

***Is it possible to create a nullable boolean that can't be undefined in typescript?***

Comment: I think you cannot prevent anything from being undefined. Because Javascript will treat anything as undefined unless you specify a value. That is the only type that is non configurable and non writable. It was designed not to be used explicitly. This is my understanding that no matter a variable or property of any type, you cannot restrict it to not have a value of undefined.

Comment: Note when I say that undefined was not designed to be used explicitly. For that you have null.

Comment: Turn on the `strictNullChecks` flag

Comment: RAR (Repeat After Ryan): turn on `strictNullChecks`

Comment: @VinodBhavnani that is arguable. Unional, I love the RAR! <3